# FirstOrDefaultAsync not returning updated data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code in my controller:

```
var getStatusLevel1 = await _repo.CheckStatus(lotId);
var status1 = getStatusLevel1.Status;
while (status1 == null) {
    // Level 2
    var getStatusLevel2 = await _repo.CheckStatus(lotId);
    var status2 = getStatusLevel1.Status;
    if(status2 != null) {
        status1 = status2;
    }
}
```

When I'm again querying (level 2), it does not give any updated result.
*** Note: Some background process is changing the data**.

Refer to the checkStatus() below:

```
    public async Task<ZRequestBn> CheckStatus(int lotId)
    {
        return await _context.ZRequestBn.FirstOrDefaultAsync( u => u.LotId == lotId);
    }
```

Every time I execute this function it returns old data.

Comment: When your code will work I advice you to put it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Title is misleading. Can't see `FirstOrDefaultAsync` usage anywhere in code.

Comment: Is the reference to _context always using the same instance of your context?  If so, it's probably returning the entity that's already loaded from the database.  You'll need to reload the the entity.

Comment: await _context.Entry(ZRequestBn).ReloadAsync();

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `var status2 = getStatusLevel1.Status;` is wrong and should be `var status2 = getStatusLevel2.Status;`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use your CheckStatus method, you can just reload the entity to refresh the data.

```
await _context.Entry(ZRequestBn).ReloadAsync();
```

Or if you need separation of concerns, you can use this within your CheckStatus method as well.  Either way, you need to retrieve a fresh entity from the database, not the one that's already loaded in the context.

Alternatively, you can instantiate a new context.

```
return await new MyContext().ZRequestBn.FirstOrDefaultAsync( u => u.LotId == lotId);
```

Comment: @TejashriPatange Glad it helped.  Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your issue.